# Incorrect points plotting on ggplot subplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like the following code to show a dot at x = 10, 20 and 30 on subplots 1, 2 and 3 respectively (actually it's y = 10, 20 and 30 but the axes/coordinates are flipped). Instead it is plotting the dot at x = 30 for each one.

```
pcrtle <- c(10, 20, 30)

df <- data.frame(quartile = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), x = c(
  1, 1, 1,
  1
), y = c(25, 25, 25, 25))

plt1 <- c()

for (ii in 1:length(pcrtle)) {
  plt1[[ii]] <- ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = quartile), data = df, stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    ylab("") +
    geom_point(aes(x = 1, y = pcrtle[ii]), size = 5, shape = 21, fill = "#3d3d29")
}

plt2 <- do.call("grid.arrange", c(plt1, ncol = 1))

plt2
```

The code above produces the following plot
[image]

I use the do.call for grid.arrange as the length of Percentile will be variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to come about because of non-standard evaluation in ggplot, you can fix it by moving the point's y data outside the `aes` because it's not being evaluated in the data dataframe, to give:

```
 geom_point(aes(x = 1), y = pcrtle[ii], size = 5, shape = 21, fill = "#3d3d29")
```

[image: Output plot]

Comment: Thanks very much @Miff. That's sorted it!